# Test Automation for a website with over 8000 webpages

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, python

I have joined a team recently where I have been asked to implement automation testing for a SiteCore based website with over 8000 webpages. The exact functionality that was expected of me was to automatize the process of checking every page for broken URL / image link. I used BeautifulSoup in python for scrapping all the webpages of the website, stored it in excel file and passed it as an input to the Selenium function (written in Java) to check for broken links or images (a simple condition of checking for status code over 400). For every broken link that was found, I am storing it in another excel file along with the originating URL.

But the team wants me to use an already existing (automation testing) framework / open-source tool (instead of having me code it manually and maintain it) that checks the whole website pages for broken links/images and report them. I haven't found any such tool/script so far. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: How does a "broken link checker" tool not help? It crawls a website, lists all the broken urls. Images also use urls so they should so up aswell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LinkChecker - Python module to build link checkers. Dev status is Production/Stable. There are dozens of other tools like this, in many languages.

It makes perfect sense to use open-source debugged version of such utility instead of reinventing the wheel. BTW I got the answer by googling "check broken links python" :-)